# react-highcharts vs highcharts

Tags: javascript, npm, highcharts

As I cannot find anything on this topic through search I will ask it here.

What is the difference between these two NPM packages:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highcharts

One is directly from Highcharts and the other one not.

But my question goes a bit more into this:
Which one should be chosen and why?

Comment: You also have the official [highcharts-react](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) repository.

Comment: First is official npm package from highcharts and the second is third party highcharts wrapper for React.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is based on ReactJS you will definitely need "react-highcharts" it wraps Highcharts in React component that you can easily plug.

If you are not using React "react-highcharts" won't make any sense to you and that's why will be better to stick to just highcharts one.